# Draw sphere on white background (C++ and OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, draw

I'm trying to draw a red sphere on a white background using OpenGL. Here's the part of my code that should draw the sphere.

Part of the main entry point:

```
initialise();
glutDisplayFunc(draw_Sphere);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glutMainLoop();
```

Initialisation:

```
void initialise()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}
```

Drawing the sphere:

```
void draw_Sphere()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(200, 200, 0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glutSolidSphere(0.25, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I have no idea what's going wrong, but this won't render the sphere (it will draw the white background, though). Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: A few thoughts: I see you enable GL_LIGHTING but I don't see a light setup.  You do a glTranslatef in X and Y but not Z: but I think you want the X and Y to be zero, and the Z to be translated since the default camera is looking along the Z axis.  I forget if that Z should be positive or negative.  Next, no need to push/pop the matrix around the call to glutSolidSphere.  With the default camera matrix.  I suggest starting with a working tutorial that gets the setup right, then adding your call to glutSolidSphere.  Try http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using Matrices

Consider setting up a proper model, view and projection matrices for this. Then you will have more control on what you see.

## Solution

Drop the `glTranslatef(200, 200, 0);` line as with this you are getting the sphere out of the frustum. And you should see the sphere.